# Angular: check if one of the ng-content slots provided

Tags: html, angular, ng-content

I have component template with multiple `ng-content` elements:

```html
      <div class="form__general">
        <ng-content select="[general]"></ng-content>
      </div>

      <div class="form__footer">
        <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
      </div>
```

How can I check inside `*ngIf` condition is `#footer` is provided?

I tried something like this, but this does not work:

```html
      <div *ngIf="#footer" class="form__footer">
        <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove # from the condition check.

> Sample Code Snippet:
>
> **app.component.html**

```
<h1 #footer>Welcome</h1>

<child-comp>
    <div *ngIf="footer.innerText === 'Welcome'" class="form__footer">
        Hi There
    </div>
</child-comp>
```

> **child.component.html**

```
<ng-content select=".form__footer"></ng-content>
```